# Carregar e manipular um formulário de um site externo

Tags: php, formulário, iframe

Olá, eu preciso incorporar este site no meu site: https://geoobras.tce.mg.gov.br/cidadao/ para que a pessoa consiga fazer a consulta por ele.

Usando iframe funciona direitinho, porém eu precisava manipular o primeiro campo (município) para que ficasse fixo numa das opções.

Outra coisa que eu queria fazer também seria reduzir a quantidade de informações que aparecem, porem não posso cortar usando `cut` do css e nem colocar margens negativas no iframe, porque a segunda página (a que aparece após o usuário submeter o form) é maior que a primeira, então se eu corto o iframe eu corto informação da segunda página.

O que eu quero fazer é possível? Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

`<iframe src="https://geoobras.tce.mg.gov.br/cidadao/" style="width: 100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>`

Meu site é feito em php, pelo que eu vi no geoobras, o formulário leva para `default.aspx`

Comment: Não existe nenhuma API que faz a consulta que precisa?

Comment: Não existe, infelizmente :(

Comment: Já verificou se eles oferecem alguma API? algum script para inclusão?

Comment: Olá @FláviaNunes você pode fazer uma coisa meio complicada porem vai funcionar, usar o scrapy ou selenium em python ou usar guzzle em php, para fazer o seguinte, você monta a sua pagina e na sua pagina nela você coloca os campos que realmente quer que o usuário digite, após isso, no seu servidor você trata, e manda para algum desse que falei e eles fazem a consulta na pagina e retorna as informações para você. da uma pesquisada sobre o assunto que vai baixar bastante conteúdo. isso é claro se não existir nenhuma api pronta.